# Membership.GetUser() returns NULL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I have multiple applications that share a Membership database.  In the Submission controller, I try to get the username:

```
var userId = (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
```

But it always give me the error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

It works just fine on the other applications.  I only have problem with this application.  Below is my Submission controller:

```
[Authorize]
[OutputCache(Duration = 0)]
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public class SubmissionsController : Controller
{
    private ProductionReportDBEntities db = new ProductionReportDBEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var u = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
        ...
    }
}
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do something similar to you where you have common DB and different membership providers, the approach that worked for me is the following one:

In the web.config file of your project you should have something like

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ConnString" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="ApplicationName" description="Description" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Encrypted" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

If you want to have several Memberships you will need to add one more line below the existing  node in your web.config

After that the next step would be adding the application to your [aspnet_applications] table and in the [aspnet_users] table, you will need to include a user that belongs to that application (have in mind that the ApplicationName attribute in the  have to match you application name).

Once you have this you can look for the user with the following code:

```
 MembershipUser user = null;
        foreach (MembershipProvider prov in Membership.Providers)
        {
            int rec = 0;
            prov.FindUsersByName(username, 0, 1, out rec);

            if (rec > 0)
                user = prov.GetUser(username: username, userIsOnline: true);
        }
```

Let me know if it works for you as well :)